# Rows, Cols, and Tables in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I'm a React JS Beginner and I'm trying to create a table (or grid) by React Js. I've searched through different sites and tried different ways. I've used react-row, react-bootstrap, react-table, and followed the instructions step by step. However, none of them works. I tried to display a row with 3 cells but all of them displayed 3 rows :<<. Please, can you guys give me other ways or show me how to use the 3 mentioned libraries clearly. Thanks

Here is one of my case,

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, Component} from 'react';
import AppNavBar from './AppNavBar.js';
import {Container, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
const RestaurantReview = (props) => {
    return(
        <>
            <AppNavBar />
            <Row>
                <Col>1</Col>
                <Col>2</Col>
                <Col>3</Col>
            </Row>
        </>
    )
}

export default RestaurantReview
```

Comment: Can you provide your code? It would be more beneficial to provide reproducible example so we can debug your code.

Comment: I just added, can you check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a stylesheet that you're referencing in this component you can add the below line at the top of it to ensure you pull in the default bootstrap styles.

```
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

Then you can import that stylesheet in your `App.js` component or into `RestaurantReview.js` whichever you prefer. Preferably in `App.js` that way you can use the bootstrap styles in other components.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import RestaurantReview from "./components/RestarauntReview";
import "./styles.css"; // this is where you import the bootstrap styles

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RestaurantReview />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This way you won't have to change any of your code in `RestaurantReview.js`

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-demo-forked-7bnrx?file=/src/App.js:0-233) with all of the code.